# Is there anyway to perform a Count() when using Min()?

Tags: mysql, sql

The statement below is to get all non-duplicate IDs from the products table. Is there a way I can get the total count of rows that are outputted by this sql statement?

```
select min(product_id) from products 
where market_code = 'germany'
group by product_code
```

### sample table data:

```
product_id   market_code   product_code
   1            uk             AAA
   1            uk             AAA
   1            uk             AAA
   2           germany         BAA
   2           germany         BAA
   3            uk             BAA
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why it wouldn't simply return 1 row.

Comment: @DanBracuk - It won't return 1 row, because of `group by product_code`, if you removed the `group by` it would return only one row

Comment: @DanBracuk Vector vs Scalar aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    select min(product_id) from products 
    where market_code = 'germany'
    group by product_code
) AS t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your query is not what you said "The statement below is to get all unique/non-duplicate IDs from the products table." , It will select lowest product_id for product_code , not unique , for example if there are product_id - 2 and product_id - 3 for product_code A , it will only return product_id - 2 , it is a minimum value not unique , if you want unique you could do this way

```
SELECT product_code,product_id,count(*) 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY product_code,product_id
```

if you want just unique/non-duplicate ID-s and their count you can select with this query

```
SELECT product_id,count(*) 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
select min(product_id)
from products 
where market_code = 'germany'
group by product_code;
```

is going to have as many rows as there are product code values in Germany.  If you assume that a given product id never has two codes (which is true of your sample data), then the following counts the products in Germany without using product id at all:

```
select count(distinct product_code)
from products
where market_code = 'germany';
```